# Error: invalid format type (argument="format", value=true, code=INVALID_ARGUMENT, version=abi/5.6.1)

Tags: ethereum, blockchain, smartcontracts, ethers.js, openzeppelin

I am trying to deploy an upgradable contract using hardhat, i have installed all the dependencies and it compiles successfully however when i want to deploy it throws this error

```
Error: invalid format type (argument="format", value=true, code=INVALID_ARGUMENT, version=abi/5.6.1)
    at Logger.makeError (/Users/mac/Documents/MEME MASTER/node_modules/@ethersproject/logger/src.ts/index.ts:261:28)
    at Logger.throwError (/Users/mac/Documents/MEME MASTER/node_modules/@ethersproject/logger/src.ts/index.ts:273:20)
    at Logger.throwArgumentError (/Users/mac/Documents/MEME MASTER/node_modules/@ethersproject/logger/src.ts/index.ts:277:21)
    at ConstructorFragment.format (/Users/mac/Documents/MEME MASTER/node_modules/@ethersproject/abi/src.ts/fragments.ts:720:20)
    at /Users/mac/Documents/MEME MASTER/node_modules/@ethersproject/abi/src.ts/interface.ts:167:63
    at Array.map (<anonymous>)
    at Interface.format (/Users/mac/Documents/MEME MASTER/node_modules/@ethersproject/abi/src.ts/interface.ts:167:36)
    at /Users/mac/Documents/MEME MASTER/node_modules/@openzeppelin/hardhat-upgrades/src/utils/deploy-impl.ts:113:41
    at resumeOrDeploy (/Users/mac/Documents/MEME MASTER/node_modules/@openzeppelin/upgrades-core/src/deployment.ts:76:30)
    at async /Users/mac/Documents/MEME MASTER/node_modules/@openzeppelin/upgrades-core/src/impl-store.ts:63:23 {
  reason: 'invalid format type',
  code: 'INVALID_ARGUMENT',
  argument: 'format',
  value: true
}
```

[image: Message On Terminal]

I am trying to deploy on goerli. I have tried other testnets as well but no luck

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue once, it was because dependencies had conflicts, when you do npm/yarn/pnpm install check that all required peer deps have correct matching versions.

Because if you use hardhat that is meant for ethers 5.x.x with 6.x.x you're likely to get this error.